# How to set min input[type=number] value to initial value upon page load?

Tags: html, input, onchange

I need to make an input[type=number] field only accept numbers that are larger than the initial value, not lower. I have tried:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="SOA_Serial" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" style="max-width:150px;">Serial: </label>
    <input type="number" id="serial_input" class="form-control" name="SOA_Serial" style="width:330px;" value="<?php echo escape($SOA_array[2]);?>" onchange="document.getElementById('serial_input').min=this.value;">
</div>
```

However, there are problems.

1) First click of the arrow, it allows me to decrement once, then not again. It needs to not decrement at all.

2) If I increment, then decrement, I can't go back to the original number because of the onchange.

How can I either a) Prevent decrement lower than the original value, or b) disable the down arrow completely? Is that possible?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thought that was complete enough. Added the whole div now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```js
let changed = (element) => {
  let initial = element.defaultValue * 1;
  if (element.value < initial) {
    element.value = initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="24" onchange="changed(this)">
```

***Edit:** I've just realize there's a built-in attribute just for this cause, so JavaScript is a bit of an overkill*

```html
<input type="number" value="24" min="24">
```

Comment: Is all of that within the change() function?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I see what you did with "let changed = (element)". However, it still allows me to decrement after clicking twice.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce I've edited my answer. Are you sure you can decrement the value below 24?

Comment: I didn't realize it changed back as soon as focus went away on the input. It works! Thank you!

Comment: Your first edit was perfect (without the defaultValue * 1).

Comment: That works even better. I just echoed my initial value (since it's a php variable) within the min like: min="<?php echo $SOA_array[2]);?>" and it works like a charm. Thanks for helping and teaching me something.